# fabric-ca-server affiliation command line option

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Which fabric-ca-server command line option can be used to specify affiliation (akin to `affiliations` section of fabric-ca-server-config.yaml)?

Comment: After the CA is started I think you would use the `fabric-ca-client` to add/remove affiliations.

Comment: That works for me, @rthatcher. Thank you.